# ngModel "Cannot set property of undefined" when using indexer

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following markup

```
<div ng-app>
    <table ng-controller="test">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
                <td ng-repeat="col in cols">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="row[col].val" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

controller looks like this

```
function test($scope) {
    $scope.cols = ["col1", "col2", "col3"];
    $scope.rows = [{
        col1: { val: "x"}
    }, {
        col2: { val: "y" }
    }]
}
```

When i try to set column value that does not yet exist, i get

> "Cannot set property 'val' of undefined".

Example is here http://jsfiddle.net/z9NkG/2/

In documentation is note:

> ngModel will try to bind to the property given by evaluating the
>   expression on the current scope. If the property doesn't already exist
>   on this scope, it will be created implicitly and added to the scope.

But it fails when using indexer instead of property name.

**Is there a way to define ngModel expression dynamically or am i misusing angular?**

Comment: nice workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/z9NkG/4/

Comment: Yes it is failing on usage of indexer.

Comment: @Cherniv, I want to be able to create those values that are disabled in your example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And what about:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="row[col].val" ng-init="row[col] = row[col] || {}" />
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z9NkG/8/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your model, but I think you are using a 2 dimensional array. I'm oversimplifying, not knowing,

make cols collection a child or rowsL

```
function test($scope) {
    $scope.colnames = ["col1", "col2", "col3"];
    $scope.rows = [{
        cols: { col1: "x"},  { col2: "y"}
    }, {
        cols: { col1: "z"},  { col2: "a"}
    }]
}
```

And then use nested ng-repeats

```
  <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
            <td ng-repeat="col in row.cols">
                <input type="text" ng-model="col.val" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: this doesn't work with my model. i added model definition to my question. you can also check jsfiddle link

Comment: @maxlego, I may be missing something, but cols array is a child of rows. thereby, each row should have an array of cols. so my example should be modifiable (it was meant to be general, a little obtuse...) check the new updated

Comment: No columns do not belong to each row. First reason is that if i have no rows i want to be able to show column names. Second reason is that columns can be added

Comment: @maxlego, you can have an array of column names independent and still nest cols array in each row. Again, I may be missing something, but this feels like the natural OOP way to do this.

Comment: this would mean that if i add or remove column i should do it in every row

Comment: @maxlego, not sure about greater implementation. But I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you're setting an undefined property of an undefined object as the input's model. Angular does indeed automatically create the corresponding variables for your model binding, but to do so, you would have to bind the input directly to the `row[col]` property instead of `row[col].val` :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="row[col]" />
```

Here's the live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/z9NkG/9/

Answer (score 0):

try this

make changes in controller 
add below code

```
 $scope.cols.forEach(function(x, y) {
        angular.forEach($scope.rows, function(i, j) {
            if ((i[x])== null)
                i[x] = {};

        });
    })
```

yo can refer fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/z9NkG/10/